# $\mathcal{C}$ a family of connected sets with connected union. For all $C \in \mathcal{C}$ there is $C' \in \mathcal{C}$ with $C\cup C'$ connected.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

It is easy to show that if the union of a finite family $\mathcal{C}$ of (more than one) connected sets is connected, then for any $C \in \mathcal{C}$ there must always be some other $C' \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $C \cup C'$ is connected. In fact I think this works if $\mathcal{C}$ is a locally finite collection.

But what if $\mathcal{C}$ is not a locally finite collection? I suspect that such $C'$ may not exist in general, but I cannot find a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about $\mathcal{C} = \{[\frac{1}{n}, 1]\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\{0\}\}$?

Comment: Great answer! Better than the one I thought of right after asking the question, $\mathcal{C} = \{\{x\}\ |\ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, which is so trivial. I asked a stupid question.

Comment: Not at all. You should always question why you need the hypotheses that are put in place. Finding counterexamples helps to develop mathematical maturity. Great question and a great answer (by you).